# Google Firebase OrderByChild is not working with nested dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Order by child (name) is not working when dynamic keys comes between actual reference and data.

**Here is my code:**

```
firebase.database().ref('/usersProfile').orderByChild('name').on('value', function(snapshot) {
  callback(snapshot);
});
```

```js
callback(snapshot) {
  //console.log(snapshot);
  let data = snapshot.val();
  self.users = [];
  for(let key in data) {
    let value = data[key];
    value.categId = key;
    self.users.push(value);
  }
}
```

And here is my data collected over server:

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what `callback()` does with the snapshot. But most likely you're not looping over the results. When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Comment: callback(snapshot); is a callback function that Run code:
let data = snapshot.val();
            self.users = [];
            for(let key in data) {
                let value = data[key];
                value.categId = key;
                self.users.push(value);
            }

Comment: Added callback() function, please see the updated question.

Answer (score 2):

I think your forward slash might be the problem. It should probably look something like this:

```
firebase.database().ref().child("usersProfile").orderByChild("name").on("value", function(snapshot) {
  callback(snapshot);
});
```

Comment: Hi! Like Frank said, without giving us a little more context, it's hard for us to help completely. Could you create a jsfiddle or show us more of the code?

Comment: Added callback() function, please see the updated question.